# What might I be doing wrong that Panda3D won't properly import ShowBase?

Tags: python, import, panda3d

Trying to get up and running with Panda3D. I can't seem to get anything going with the ShowBase class.

I use the following code, as instructed by the website:

```
    from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase

class myApp(ShowBase):

    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)

app = myApp()
app.run()
```

Now, when I go to test it,  I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\POWER\Documents\python_programs\panda3d.py", line 1, in <module>
    from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
  File "C:\Users\POWER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 12, in <module>
    from panda3d.core import *
  File "C:\Users\POWER\Documents\python_programs\panda3d.py", line 1, in <module>
    from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
ImportError: cannot import name 'ShowBase' from 'direct.showbase.ShowBase' (C:\Users\POWER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py)
```

Using Windows 10, Python 3.7. Any help?

Comment: [This question may be related, or even an (indirect) duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506790/panda3d-error-no-module-named-direct-showbase-showbase-in-python-2-7).

Comment: I do note that you're using the 32-bit version of Python; any specific reason for that?  You generally want to use the 64-bit version of Python and Panda3D.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved by renaming the files in the folder, they have not to be called with the same name of the library. I had a file called panda3d.py and it doesn't work, now i renamed it and it words. Try to change the name of your files

Comment: I did exactly what you said, naming it as panda3d.py... and changing it has worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have Panda3D installed, if not then go the command prompt and type:
pip install Panda3D

Another error in your code is the indentation when importing ShowBase, try importing with any indentation.

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
```

If you have any further questions try checking the [Panda3D Manual](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/?title=ShowBase)

Comment: I have already installed Panda3D, and even tried to install it again to make sure. The indentation was just a problem with the formatting when I posted this.